# How to find element that should not be there in c# Selenium drivers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I'm using Firefox Selenium webdrivers and Visual studio with C#.

I need to check if exists element that should not be there.

For example, in the pop-up menu are 3 elements:

```
element01
element02
element03
```

I have created test case to check these elements.

In the new build of tested software, by mistake, in the popup menu are 4 elements now.

```
element01
element02
element03
element04
```

How to write to created test case that element04 should not be there ?

How to check element04 that should not be there ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You cannot find it if is not there, you could get a selector for that element and use an existing method to check the element is not there or just use find and see if returns null else throw exception.

Comment: Check the size of the findElements call. If you have the id or name or text of the three expected elements, remove them and see whats left in the list. Fail or pass accordingly.

Comment: How can I to check the size of the findElements call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to checking the presence of your elements 01 through 03, also check the number of elements in the pop up menu (as mentioned by @Grasshopper's comment) :

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

var elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("yourPopUpMenuId"));
Assert.AreEqual(3, elements.Count);
```

Checking the number of elements present assures you that there are no more than expected and you probably don't know what name the additional erroneous elements will have.